# Rails time zone display over daylight savings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone

I have a booking app where I display a range of booking slots for the user to pick from. My times are all stored in UTC in the database and to display the times in the view I use

`time.to_datetime.in_time_zone(event.default_time_zone).strftime('%k:%M')`

This works perfectly however when a user views times in the future (once daylight savings come into account and the clocks go back), the time is being displayed as 1 hour earlier.

See example below. Both dates have the time slots stored in the DB as the same:

[image]

Anything I can do to deal with this?

Comment: So you have the opposite problem to the one people normally have. You need to schedule your available slots in local time when you create them, and convert the slot times to UTC as you store them taking account of the daylight saving offset for each one. Then when you display you'll get the right answer.

Comment: Ahhh yes I think you are correct. technically they should be stored 1 hour different in the DB too!